# Pandoc markdown to PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm looking to convert my Markdown book to a PDF.

I've done a lot of research and it seems that Pandoc is the best choice for this. It seems pandoc converts the markdown to latex and then to a PDF.

The problem I am running into is including external images. Ideally I would have the process grab the remote images off the net and put them into the pdf.

I'm hitting this error:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `http://wes.io/QYGG/content.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.84 ...degraphics{http://wes.io/QYGG/content.png}
```

I have MacTex installed and the command I'm running is `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`

I've never used latex before, so I'm a bit at a loss of how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this LaTex question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document), you can't directly reference URL images from within LaTeX, though they have a potential LaTeX-hacking option available at the link.

Local image files are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of pandoc fetch external images before passing them on to LaTeX.

Alternatively, you could use ConTeXt instead of LaTeX which natively supports fetching images from URLs:

```
$ pandoc -t context test.md -o test.pdf
```